# Does an algebra automorphism of $M_n(R)$ preserves the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

These days, I am playing around Skolem Noether for matrix algebras, and a question arises.

If $F$ is a field , a by-product of Skolem Noether implies that any $F$-algebra automorphism $\rho$ of $M_n(F)$ preserves the characteric polynomial, that is $\chi_{\rho(M)}=\chi_M$ for all $M\in M_n(F)$.

**Question 1.** Can we prove that any $F$-algebra automorphism $\rho$ of $M_n(F)$ preserves the characteric polynomial **without using the fact that $\rho$ is inner ?** (I would like to use this fact to give a constructive proof of Skolem Noether)

**Question 2.** More generally, let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $\rho$ be an $R$-algebra automorphism. Is is true that $\rho$ preserves the characteristic polynomial ??

It seems to be true for integral domains: if $R$ is a domain, let $K$ be its quotient field.
Then $\rho\otimes Id_K$ is an automorphism of $M_n(K)$ and hence is inner (even if $\rho$ isn't), so the result follows easily, since $M$ may be viewed as a matrix with values in $K$.

If the answer for Question 2 is positive in full generality, I would be grateful to have an elementary argument (or at least, as much as possible).

Comment: I haven't thought about it too carefully, so this comment might have an error (or otherwise not be that useful), but it seems like you can bootstrap your argument for question 2 to extend to all reduced rings. I'm thinking something like: consider the reduction morphism $R \to R/P$ for all prime ideals $P$ of $R$. If $\rho$ is an $R$-algebra automorphism, then you've already explained that for $\rho' := \rho \otimes Id_{R/P}$ and any $M \in M_{n}(R)$, we have $\chi_{\rho'(\overline{M})} = \chi_{\overline{M}}$, where $\overline{M} \in M_{n}(R/P)$ is just the reduction of $M$. My suspicion is...

Comment: ...that the reduction of $\chi_{\rho(M)}$ mod $P$ is $\chi_{\rho'(\overline{M})}$, and likewise with $\chi_{M}$ and $\chi_{\overline{M}}$, so we've shown that $\chi_{\rho(M)}$ and $\chi{M}$ agree mod every prime $P$ of $R$. This shows that they agree up to nilpotents of $R$, hence agree on the nose if $R$ is reduced.

Comment: Since question 2 deals with arbitrary rings, it's equivalent to ask about determinants instead of the characteristic polynomial, i.e. for any ring $R$ and $\rho$ an $R$-algebra automorphism of $M_n(R)$, is $\det \circ \rho = \det$? Perhaps one can use a characterization of $\det$ among all maps $M_n(R) \to R$ for this